# How to get the intervals containing same value using a mySQL or Cassandra query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cassandra

I have a sql table like this:

History Table

`+-------------+
| DATE | VALUE |
|03/06 |1      |
|03/07 |0      |
|03/08 |0      |
|03/09 |0      |
|03/10 |1      |
|03/11 |0      |
|03/12 |1      |
+--------------+`

I want the list of intervals like [[03/07,03/10], [03/11,03/12]] to be returned. Here an interval is a set of records with value 0. I want the [start,end) dates for such intervals.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions.  Simply assign a group based on the number of "1"s up to each value:

```
select min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*, sum(value = 1) over (order by date) as grp
      from history_table
     ) t
where value = 0
group by grp;
```

Answer (score 1):

**For MySQL 5.7 & Less**:

This query also handles edge case along with the given requirements.

```
For below input

`+-------------+
| DATE | VALUE |
|03/05 |0      |    -- When date starts with 0
|03/06 |1      |
|03/07 |0      |
|03/08 |0      |
|03/09 |0      |
|03/10 |1      |
|03/11 |0      |
|03/12 |1      |
|03/13 |0      |    -- When date ends with 0
+--------------+`

Output: It will create range for both start and end date too.
+-------------------------+
| Start_Date | End_Date   |
| 2019-03-05 | 2019-03-06 |  -- Included for first date as 0
| 2019-03-07 | 2019-03-10 |
| 2019-03-11 | 2019-03-12 |
| 2019-03-13 | 2019-03-13 |  -- Included for the last date as 0, if you want you can make End_Date here as 2019-03-14 or current date too
+-------------------------+
```

**Assumption**: No dates will be missing in between from Min to Max dates.

```
SELECT 
    final.Start_Date,
    final.End_Date
FROM (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN a.`date` = t.Min_date AND a.value = 0 THEN @a:= a.`date`
            WHEN a.value = 1 AND b.value = 0 THEN @a:= b.`date`
            ELSE NULL
        END AS Temp_date,
        @a AS Start_Date,
        CASE
            WHEN a.`date` = t.Max_date AND a.value = 0 THEN a.`date`  -- to make End_Date of last date as 2019-03-14 add one day here and for current day use CURRENT_DATE
            WHEN a.value = 0 AND b.value = 1 THEN b.`date` 
            ELSE NULL
        END AS End_Date
    FROM date_history a
    LEFT JOIN date_history b ON a.date = b.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT MIN(`date`) AS Min_date, MAX(`date`) as Max_date FROM date_history) AS t ON 1
    ORDER BY a.`date`
) AS final
WHERE Start_date IS NOT NULL AND End_Date IS NOT NULL;
```

**If no edge case handling** is required. A little bit simplified solution would be

```
SELECT 
    final.Start_Date,
    final.End_Date
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF(  a.value = 1 AND b.value = 0, @a:= b.`date`, NULL) AS Temp_date,
        @a AS Start_Date,
        IF( a.value = 0 AND b.value = 1 , b.`date`, NULL) AS End_Date
    FROM date_history a
    INNER JOIN date_history b ON a.date = b.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY
    INNER JOIN (SELECT @a:= null) AS t ON 1
    ORDER BY a.`date`
) AS final
WHERE Start_date IS NOT NULL AND End_Date IS NOT NULL;

---------------------------------------------------------------------
or Using variables: This would be fast as table is scanned only once.

SELECT 
    Start_date,
    End_Date
FROM (
    SELECT
        IF(@prev_value = 1 AND a.value = 0, @a:= a.`date`, NULL) AS Temp_date,
        @a AS Start_Date,
        IF( @prev_value = 0 AND a.value = 1, a.`date`, NULL) AS End_Date, 
        @prev_date:= a.`date` AND @prev_value:= a.value
    FROM date_history a,
    (SELECT @prev_date:= null, @prev_value:= null, @a:= '0000-00-00') as b
    ORDER BY a.date
) AS final
WHERE Start_Date <> '0000-00-00' and End_Date IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Khazana, if it solves your problem, do accept the answer.:)